# Outlook 2013 "sender is in ... Address Book" rule breaks all subsequent rules

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, rules, address-book

Using Outlook 2013 desktop app in Windows 10 with an Exchange server. I'm trying to create rules that sort emails into folders based, among other things, on the sender. Once upon a time I put lists of people directly in the rules, but started getting errors saying I had too big/many rules.

I then noticed that you can supposedly use a "sender is in ... Address Book" rule as the condition, so I set up custom contact lists in my email account with the desired names, and pointed the rules at those. I thought this was working, until I recently noticed that some of my rules weren't working. I narrowed it down to these address book conditions: Any rule following an address book check in another rule doesn't get run automatically at all (running all rules manually works fine).

I've tried all kinds of things:

- Deleting and recreating the rules, including using /cleanrules.
- Deleting and recreating the contact lists.
- Disabling use of the contact lists as address books, then removing all address books from the account settings list (not sure why they still showed up), then re-enabling.
- Repairing account and .ost file.

Any idea why this isn't working? Is the feature just plain broken in Outlook 2013?

P.S. The way I caught this was to have a rule that marks items sent from myself as read, and then send emails to myself.

**Update:**
I was able to prove to myself that any "sender is in specified Address Book" rule breaks automatic rule application via the following test:

1. Add myself to "test" contacts list:

   - Go to Sent Items folder and open an email that I previously sent.
   - Right-click on my name and click Add to Outlook Contacts.
   - Go to People view.
   - Right-click Contacts (not "My Contacts" for some reason) and create a contact group named "test".
   - Click Contacts.
   - Drag entry for myself into "test".
2. Create address book rule to delete messages from myself:

   - Return to Mail view.
   - Click Rules->Manage Rules & Alerts->New Rule
   - Click "Apply rule on messages I receive"
   - Click Next >
   - Check "sender is in specified Address Book"
   - Click "specified" in bottom pane.
   - Click "test", Add, Close
   - Click Next >
   - Check "delete it"
   - Click Finish, OK, OK, Yes (if prompted)
3. Test the rule:

   - Send email to myself
   - Observe that the email is not deleted
   - Observe that any subsequent rules are not processed, regardless of whether this one has a "stop" action

Comment: When you are creating a rule, there is a option "stop processing more rules". And you can also change the order in which the rules take effect via Move Up andd Move Down.

Comment: @Aidan No, that's a red herring. "Stop processing more rules" is only supposed to apply if the conditions apply and the action is taken. If "stop processing more rules" is not enabled on "move item to folder" rules, then copies of the message end up in multiple folders. I have "stop processing more rules" enabled on ALL of my move rules, but only the address book ones are causing problems.

Comment: Update: I've been able to determine that the "stop" action is also a red herring. See update to my question.